# Trying to install Auth for CI: Call to undefined method CI_Loader::setdata()

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication

I have been trying to implement an auth system for Codeigniter. I wanted to save time, though it hasn't succeeded so far.

The system I'm trying to implement is: http://codeigniter.com/wiki/auth/

Currently I have some forms working, but the registration form generates a fatal error:
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method CI_Loader::setdata() in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/CI+Login/system/application/controllers/auth.php on line 159

Anyone has an idea what that is about? Anyone has got this system running?

thx.

EDIT:
The code that generates the error is:

```
if ($this->config->item('auth_use_security_code'))
    $this->authlib->register_init();
            $data['countries'] = $this->Usermodel->getCountries();
$this->load->setdata($data);
```

The problem is that load does not contain a method named setdata, has it in a previous version of CI or what can I make of this?

Comment: Have you read the article on the same page you referenced to?! Read the `Links` section!

Comment: omg. idk why I missed that, probably because I was tired from trying to fix other problems on my own before this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$this->load->vars($data);
```

or remove this line and use the second parameter of the $this->load->view() function.

```
$this->load->view($this->config->item('auth_register_view'),$data);
```